# sqoop is not able to read the config file from the s3 bucket

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3

Hello all we are using the hive spark and sqoop. Currently the sqoop .conf file in under the `/home/hadoop`, but we want to secure the .conf and read it from the secure s3 bucket. But the problem when we read the file from secure `s3` it gives the error. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
conf="aws s3 cp s3://hadoop-secure-store/dev/project/dev.conf /home/hadoop" ;;

/usr/bin/aws: line 14: import: command not found
/usr/bin/aws: line 15: import: command not found
/usr/bin/aws: line 17: syntax error near unexpected token 'LC_CTYPE','
/usr/bin/aws: line 17: `if os.environ.get('LC_CTYPE', '') == 'UTF-8':
```